# Calculating the Maximal Lyapunov Exponent for a Hamiltonian System

Tags: hamiltonian-formalism, chaos-theory, complex-systems

I am consider the following Hamiltonian: $$\mathcal{H} = \frac{1}{2}(\dot{x}^2 + \dot{y}^2) + \frac{1}{2}(x^2 + y^2) + x^2y - \frac{y^3}{3}.$$ The first step I took were to solve the equations of motion which gave me 4 functions: $x(t)$, $\dot{x}(t)$, $y(t)$, $\dot{y}(t)$. However in the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_exponent) article on Lyapunov Exponents, their equation for the maximal Lyapunov exponent $$\lambda(x_0) = \lim_{n\to0}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\ln{|f'(x_i)|}$$ depends only on one function $f(x)$. How does this generalize to my system?

Comment: Related: [How to calculate the maximal Lyapunov exponent(s) of a multidimensional system?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/388676/75633)

Comment: Also, the equation you list is for discrete systems, not EDOs; and the linked Wikipedia entry already [generalizes to more dimensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_exponent#Definition_of_the_Lyapunov_spectrum), using the Jacobian matrix of the system.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to calculate the maximal Lyapunov exponent(s) of a multidimensional system?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/388676/how-to-calculate-the-maximal-lyapunov-exponents-of-a-multidimensional-system)

Comment: Yeah I looked at the post but I couldn't figure out what the maps f(x_n, y_n) and g(x_n, y_n) would be since after solving Hamilton's equations, I got functions of t. Also would my state vector be the position or a 4d vector also including the velocities?

Comment: Dan, you're right, my bad, that was for maps, not EDOs. Maybe [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/320199/75633) is more helpful, with its links to papers [1](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02128236) and [2](http://www.mat.unimi.it/users/antonio/ricerca/papers/lyap2.pdf).

Comment: I read through the paper and I didn't get how this is useful for my problem. Like they gave a formula of the maximal lyapunov exponent for a differentiable mapping $T$ but what would that be in my case?

Comment: Dan, actually the Benettin paper covers the continuous case as well. If you didn't consider it clear, you might prefer to consult [Ott's book](https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9780511803260), chapter 4.4, which has a more thorough description of the method.